# Zoom effect on Android SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am developing a Car Race Game. I am able to move, stop, accelerate. But i want that when i press screen then `car(bitmap of car image)` should look like, it had jumped on its place.I am using `surfaceview`to draw view

I do not want to use **3D openGL**. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally i used.On touch event, i create a bigger bitmap and draw it on same place. So it will give zoom effect

```
Bitmap bitmapToZoom;  // Create a Bitmap
// Now zoom it 
bitmapToZoom=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapToZoom, bitmapToZoom.getWidth()+30,bitmapToZoom.getHeight()+30, null); 
//now draw it again
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToZoom, 0,0,null);
```

So now finally, Zooming actor on touch code will be like this. Class Name **ZoomonTouc.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class ZoomonTouc extends SurfaceView {
public Bitmap mMyChracter;

public ZoomonTouc(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mMyChracter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mMyChracter, mMyChracter.getWidth()/2, mMyChracter.getHeight()/2, null);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    RectF rectF = new RectF(mMyChracter.getWidth()/2, mMyChracter.getHeight()/2, mMyChracter.getWidth() + 100,
            mMyChracter.getHeight() + 100);
    if (rectF.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
        mMyChracter = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mMyChracter,
                mMyChracter.getWidth() + 10, mMyChracter.getHeight() + 10,
                false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

To test it properly create one activity and set above surface to activity background

```
setContentView(new ZoomonTouc(this));
```